# Setting auto dimension on core-image causes it not to render

Tags: html, css, polymer, core-image, web-component

I have a core-image component in my page that I'm sizing to fit the width of the div it is within.

```
<div class="content">

  <core-image class="sized gray" sizing="contain" 
              preload fade src="Koala.jpg">
  </core-image>

</div>
```

Sizing this with absolute dimensions is fine, eg

```
.sized {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

However, sizing with auto or 100% height will cause it not to render,

```
.sized {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Removing the `sizing="contain"` fixes this issue somewhat however I'm using it's functionality.

What am I doing wrong, or what can I do to enable dynamic height based on width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting width/height to `auto`/percentage does not cause it not to render. It causes it to have zero size.

1. `sizing=` involves no magic behind, it [simply sets](https://github.com/Polymer/core-image/blob/master/core-image.html#L213) the [`background-size` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) of the `core-image`’s host.
2. Once set, it forces `core-image` to render [another template](https://github.com/Polymer/core-image/blob/master/core-image.html#L213). *That’s why not specifying `sizing` seems to solve an issue.*
3. Custom elements have still the limited support even in modern browsers. That said, `auto` for width/height is working uhmmm... not always as expected (at least in my experience).

There is a possibility to set w/h to percentage value, though. To do so, one should explicitly set the size of the nesting container:

```
  <template>
    <style>
      .content { width: 200px; height: 200px; }
      .sized {
        background-color: lightgray;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="content">
      <core-image class="sized gray" sizing="contain" 
                  preload fade src="Koala.jpg">
      </core-image>
    </div>
  </template>
```

Live preview: http://plnkr.co/edit/7NhNwq6IgigBmiRhI58V?p=preview

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation helps. How would you go about sizing the image to take, say 80% of the screen width? I'm trying to put the image within a paper-dialog which takes 80% of the screen width but I get the same issue trying to style the dialog to 80%. With percentages, they have zero size as you say, and I don't want to put a px amount because on mobile it will look bad. Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure that it is possible. [Examples](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/paper-elements/demo.html#paper-dialog) show the absolute positioning and size, but the size there is px-hardcoded. If you’d inspect `paper-dialog`, you’ll see it has automatically layouted `div` inside. The main purpose of this component is to devolve on default material design guidelines. In other words, it will position dialog for you and it won’t provide an easy way to “break” whatever it did.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll just try and come up with a suitable number that doesn't look too weird on most screen sizes :)